# metapost with tex label can't work in NOT bin folder but can work in the bin folder,what's the reason?

Tags: texlive, tex-core, metapost

Win 10 1903 + TeXLive 2019

the fig.mp file are

```
prologue := 3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
etex
beginfig(1);
draw (0,0)--(2cm,0);
label.top(btex $\sqrt{x}$ etex,(1cm,0));
endfig;
verbatimtex
\end{document}
\end{CJK}
etex
end
```

in the `Desktop` and the `texlive\bin\win32\`

In CMD, if the path is `Desktop`,`mpost -tex=latex fig.mp` doesn't work,and the error log is

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.00 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (kpathsea version 6.3.1)
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./fig.mpfatal:Command failed: latex mpa01092.tex; see mpxerr.log
>> fig.mp
>> fig.mpx
! ! Unable to read mpx file.
l.12 label.top(btex
                    $\sqrt{x}$ etex,(1cm,0));
Transcript written on fig.log.
```

but there is no mpxerr.log,so I think the `latex mpa01092.tex` doesn't launched for some reason.

However, I change the path to `texlive\bin\win32`,then run `mpost -tex=latex fig.mp` It can generate the fig.1 correctly.

for different work path the same file got different result,I want to know the reason.

what is weirder,On the other laptop with win 10 1903 + TexLive 2019,both path can work correctly.

Comment: It seems like your TeX utilities directory `...\texlive\bin\win32` is not in the `PATH` environment variable. So, simply running `latex file.tex` doesn't work.

Comment: `...\texlive\bin\win32`is in the PATH environment.if not , the mpost would not lauch.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by the OllyDbg.

The metapost have to launch latex to handler latex label,and it will try all of folder in path environment. But my path environment have an item `C:\Users\????\AppData\npm`(maybe generated when I upgraded to WIN 10).

The program get error and exit without any information when it meet the ? in the path.